# How to add an attachment to a work item in Visual Studio Online and C#

Tags: attachment, azure-devops

I'm having problems adding an attachment to a work item in Visual Studio Online, working from http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/reference/reference-vso-work-item-work-items-vsi#UpdateworkitemsAddanattachment

I pull email messages from an inbox that I watch, and from that, create work items in Visual Studio Online. In this instance, I have found a reply to an email, and want to add history to the vso workitem:

```
public static bool AppendHistoryToTicket(int ticketID, Message mailMessage)
{
    StringBuilder historyEntry = new StringBuilder(1024);
    historyEntry.AppendLine(mailMessage.Sender.Address + " replied on " + mailMessage.DateTimeCreated.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " GMT - ");
    historyEntry.AppendLine("");
    historyEntry.AppendLine(mailMessage.Body.Content);

    var uri = TicketURI.UpdateWorkItem(ticketID);
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
    request.ContentType = "application/json-patch+json; charset=utf-8";
    request.Method = "PATCH";
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", Settings.UserAuthorization);

    PatchProperty[] properties = new PatchProperty[]{
        new PatchProperty("add", "/fields/System.History", historyEntry.ToString()),
        new PatchProperty("add", "/relations/-", new
        {
            rel = "AttachedFile",
            url = mailMessage.Attachment.URL,
            attributes = new
            {
                comment = "This is a test"
            }
        })
    };

    byte[] byte1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(properties));
    request.ContentLength = byte1.Length;

    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        stream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);

    Logger.Write("Updating the history of ticket: #" + ticketID);

    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
        Models.Ticket result = new Models.Ticket(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DTOs.Ticket>(jsonObj.ToString()));
        return result != null;
    }
}
```

If I do this, it works (obviously without adding the attachment):

```
PatchProperty[] properties = new PatchProperty[]{
    new PatchProperty("add", "/fields/System.History", historyEntry.ToString()),
};
```

but with:

```
PatchProperty[] properties = new PatchProperty[]{
    new PatchProperty("add", "/fields/System.History", historyEntry.ToString()),
    new PatchProperty("add", "/relations/-", new
    {
        rel = "AttachedFile",
        url = mailMessage.Attachment.URL,
        attributes = new
        {
            comment = "This is a test"
        }
    })
};
```

I get a 400 (Bad Request)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want is the "Add a Hyperlink" call instead from the same MSDN page, as you are only looking to add a link (mailMessage.Attachment.URL) rather than upload a doc. That would mean rel would be "Hyperlink" instead and no comment.

Comment: Well, the add attachment specifies that it takes a url, and not the file stream/byte array? Also, I would prefer to store the file in vso, rather than having to keep a file server running, exposing confidential images.. (Currently, I expose files through an http server, but after the initial request [the one I expect vso to make to get the file using the url], I delete the file 5 mins later... I'm also assuming that a hyperlink will stay exactly that, a link to another place on the web where the file is stored/served from? An attachment would be stored on vso?

Comment: For that, you will need to first upload the attachment with http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/reference/reference-vso-work-item-attachments-vsi and then use the URL to the attachment from that response in the call to add the attachment to the work item (call you have in your post).

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot, but I'm still stuck with the actual request; I've now written the necessary code to upload the attachment to Visual Studio Online, set the mailMessage.Attachment.URL to the url returned, and now I'm at the point where the PatchProperty still breaks with a 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: I've also attempted it as a "Hyperlink", which broke with a 400 too

Comment: Scratch that, it's working ... There was something else I changed in an attempt to get it to work, and forgot to revert it.. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to hear that it's working now. We'll get the docs improved.